# Use of AND instead of JOIN with PHP based MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

From what I can tell, AND cannot be used to specify two different tables, but is there another way to simply query the exact same column names in two different tables?

Currently I have a PHP variable:

```
define('TB_RESI', 'RESI');
```

And a query like below.  I need to also query a table named RESI with the same columns...what is the best way to achieve this?

Current Query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT PictureCount AS PIC_COUNT, DATE(PictureModifiedDateTime) AS FILE_DATE, ListingRid AS HOME_ID 
            FROM ' . TB_RESI . 
            ' WHERE (COUNTY = "Lee") AND (
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP2" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP3" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP4" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP6"
            ) 
            AND (PictureCount >= 4) 
            ORDER BY EntryDate DESC';
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the table TB_RESI  and RESI? Based on the relation you can go for JOIN.

Comment: It's just a variable in PHP used to specify table name...it can be specified directly in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two tables contain a link between them use INNER JOIN to pull in the second pictures table.

```
SELECT tbla.x, tbla.y, tblb.f
FROM tbla
    INNER JOIN tblb ON tblb.id = tbla.tblbid
WHERE tbla.x = 'test' AND tblb.f > 4;
```

I have tried to keep the example as simple as possible.

Ok, it seems like you should go down the UNION route from the comments and replies you have made.

```
SELECT PictureCount AS PIC_COUNT, DATE(PictureModifiedDateTime) AS FILE_DATE, ListingRid AS HOME_ID 
            FROM (SELECT * FROM ' . TB_RESI . ' 
            WHERE (COUNTY = "Lee") AND (
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP2" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP3" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP4" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP6"
            ) 
            AND (PictureCount >= 4) 
            ORDER BY EntryDate DESC

UNION

            SELECT PictureCount AS PIC_COUNT, DATE(PictureModifiedDateTime) AS FILE_DATE, ListingRid AS HOME_ID 
            FROM (SELECT * FROM ' . TB_RESI2 . ' 
            WHERE (COUNTY = "Lee") AND (
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP2" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP3" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP4" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP6"
            ) 
            AND (PictureCount >= 4) 
            ORDER BY EntryDate DESC
```

Where TB_RESI is the name of your first table and TB_RESI2 is the second table name

Comment: I'm trying to use your example with the actual query and it's just not working.  I get a SQL error but nothing more.  Can you provide a more specific solution using the original query please?

Comment: I haven't got enough information on the two tables or the relations between them to create the code for you (or even be sure this is what is needed). I was just trying to give you a generic example of how a JOIN works. What are the two tables you are querying and what fields (if any) link them?

Comment: The columns required for select and the criteria column names are the exact same name from each table, they just house different data.  I basically need to combine the two tables into a single query.  Currently they are the exact same query but two different PHP pages.

Answer (score 1):

Use UNION to combine both tables

```
$sql = 'SELECT PictureCount AS PIC_COUNT, DATE(PictureModifiedDateTime) AS FILE_DATE, ListingRid AS HOME_ID 
            FROM (SELECT * FROM ' . TB_RESI . ' UNION SELECT * FROM ' . RESI . ') AS ALL' .
            ' WHERE (COUNTY = "Lee") AND (
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP2" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP3" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP4" OR 
                ListingOfficeMLSID = "PREFP6"
            ) 
            AND (PictureCount >= 4) 
            ORDER BY EntryDate DESC';
```

Comment: Note that this particular query will be slow due to sub-queries.

Comment: This is a bad suggestion, ``UNION`` is quite expensive and should be used only if needed, in this case it is not as far as I can see

Comment: I'm getting a SQL error on this ...syntax maybe?  What would you suggest @nrathaus?

Comment: Provide a complete error, so that we can understand the problem?

Comment: They are big tables...this is going to be a problem anyway.  I need to find another way to query the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do a JOIN for some reason, many flavors of SQL (such as MySQL) allow you to name tables, and use that name in the WHERE clause:

```
 FROM ' . TB_RESI . ' as TBR, ' . TC_RESI . ' as TCR ' .
```

...

```
 WHERE TBR.field1 = TCR.field2
```

etc. Of course, you should be looking to see if using JOIN would be a better solution.

Comment: I'm open to using join, but I can't get the JOIN to work correctly.